# Efficient Way to Build Data Frame / Data Table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data.frame that I am using to set parameters for simulations.

```
states_grid <- expand.grid(years = c(1:47), start_pct = c(0:99), sim_num = c(1:50))
```

The above code creates all the states that I would like to simulate. My issue becomes creating a data.frame to hold the outputs. What I would like to do is to create a larger data frame in which we add in an ob_num variable. The ob_num variable will run from 1 to the number of years indicated in column 1.

For example:

```
   years start_pct sim_num ob_num
1:     2        99       1      1
2:     2        99       1      2
3:     3        99       1      1
4:     3        99       1      2
5:     3        99       1      3
6:     4        99       1      1
7:     4        99       1      2
8:     4        99       1      3
9:     4        99       1      4
```

However I can't think of an efficient way to create this data frame.

Thoughts?

Edit: I tried the below suggestion but that didn't seem to do it.

The below code returns a data.table of the same size (235,000) rows.

```
states_grid <- expand.grid(years = c(1:(year_max - year_min + 1)),
                           start_pct = c(0:99),
                           sim_num = c(1:50))
states_grid <- data.table(states_grid)
setDT(states_grid)[, ob_num := 1:.N, by = years][]
```

I also tried:

```
states_grid <- setDT(states_grid)[, ob_num := 1:.N, by = years][]
```

Both methods return 235K rows.

Comment: You mean that every row in `states_grid` should be replicated `years` times , and then a new column `ob_num` should be created that contains a sequence from 1 to `years`?

Comment: Try `setDT(states_grid)[, ob_num := 1:.N, by= years][]` from `library(data.table)`

Comment: it's efficient to make a separate data.table keyed by `sim_num` and `ob_num`. You can always merge back for `years` and `start_pct` (since they are fully determined by `sim_num`).

Comment: Frank, I'm not sure what you mean there but would be happy to learn more.

FYI - I ended up writing this in Rcpp due to time constraints, but it would be greater to understand whether there is a way to handle this problem effectively (perhaps Frank's solution!).

Comment: How many rows were you expecting it to return? Could you show a small before and after example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CJ(years = c(1:47), start_pct = c(0:99), sim_num = c(1:50))[,
   .(ob_num = seq_len(years)), by = .(years, start_pct, sim_num)]
#         years start_pct sim_num ob_num
#      1:     1         0       1      1
#      2:     1         0       2      1
#      3:     1         0       3      1
#      4:     1         0       4      1
#      5:     1         0       5      1
#     ---                               
#5639996:    47        99      50     43
#5639997:    47        99      50     44
#5639998:    47        99      50     45
#5639999:    47        99      50     46
#5640000:    47        99      50     47
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I new there would be an easy/efficient way to do this way to do this